# Assigning values to multi-indexed dataframe based on index level

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multi-indexed dataframe `df1` with three indices whose values only belong to the first index. However, after a merge, the dataframe got split up which resulted in various `0`. 
Now I want to replace the `0` with the values belonging to the first index level.

Here is an extraction from the dataframe:

```
FID_Weser_Catchments_134_WQ_Stations_FINAL_LAEA... SNR1  gridcode_1               
1                                                  6631  2           543738.387186
                                                         3           543738.387186
                                                         4           543738.387186
                                                   6632  1           543738.387186
                                                         2           543738.387186
                                                         3           543738.387186
                                                         4           543738.387186
                                                   6633  2                0.000000
                                                         3                0.000000
                                                   6634  2                0.000000
                                                   6636  1           543738.387186
                                                         2           543738.387186
                                                         3           543738.387186
                                                         4           543738.387186
                                                   9473  2           543738.387186
                                                         3           543738.387186
                                                   9673  2           543738.387186
                                                         3           543738.387186
                                                         4           543738.387186
                                                   16054 1           543738.387186
```

`FID_Weser_Catchments...`, `SNR1` and `gridcode_1` are the indices but the values only originate from `index(level=0)`. 
There are in total 133 `index(level=0)` so I want to find a general function to replace the `0` with the affiliated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with replacement by Series created by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) by first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
first = s.groupby(level=0).transform('first')

s = s.mask(s == 0, first)
```